# How to find which email address my system emails come from

Tags: email, system-workflow-messages, system-settings

Here's a question with what might be an embarrassingly simple answer.

Somehow, unsubscribe or opt-out confirmation emails from our system are being sent from an email from a gmail address. We're using Mandrill to send all emails from our site, which won't tolerate emails being sent from our server from non-allowed domains; so these gmail emails get blocked. And the unlucky contact to whom the email is being sent doesn't receive the confirmation, and worse, they get put On Hold.

I'm trying to find the place where this gmail address might be being invoked. I have a distant memory that we did set up a gmail address for generic system emails...

I've tried without success looking in:

- CiviMail > Headers, Footers, and Automated Messages
- Organization Address and Contact Info
- CiviMail > Mail Accounts
- All the contacts we normally use for our system admin

I wonder what I'm missing?

This issue occurs for contacts who unsubscribe or opt-out who are not using gmail emails.

Thanks for your help in finding where on earth these gmails could be being sent from within our server!

Answer (score 1):

Two other places to look

- civicrm/admin/domain (oh you had that sorry)
- civicrm/admin/options/from_email_address

Also some old systems may have been set up with a 'civimail' user.